# 7zip unable process zip files from a folder

Tags: 7zip

I have a powershell script that is using 7zip to extract backup file from a particular folder. It was working before with rar files but the backup file compression changed from rar to zip. I was thinking the command used would work with out no changes but I am facing unexpected problems.

The command in use is

```
`7z e -y -i!Backups\TempFolder\t\* \TempFolder\t\
```

Backups\tempfolder\t\ folder has 2 zip files that were generated this morning. When I ran that command the output is

```
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Processing archive: \TempFolder\t\Admin_Backup.bak.zip
No files to process
Processing archive: \TempFolder\t\spector_Backup.bak.zip
No files to process
Archives: 2
Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 206848564
```

Could someone tell me why the e command supplied with -y is not extracting the files ? Also, I thought the generated zip files were corrupted but I extracted manually fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the option `-o` for providing the output folder. Also, you don't need the option `-i` for the input files. Try this:

```
7z e -y Backups\TempFolder\t\* -o\TempFolder\t\
```

Comment: works like a charm. The -i! was used to find a specific file from a folder within the rar but that structure has changed. cheers for quick response mate.